# How to animate FAB (expand) to a new Activity

Tags: android, android-animation

What I'd like to achieve is an effect like this:

[image]

Is it something I can achieve using `ActivityOptionsCompat` or are there other options? How can I replicate an effect like this where the FAB kinda "expands" to a new `Activity`?

Comment: you want to  know that How to implement  CircularReveal animation ?

Comment: @saeed if that's the name of the animation yes, I'd like to know how to implement it and if is it possible to use it for Activities transition

Comment: you just go trough this link https://github.com/ozodrukh/CircularReveal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These animations are related to material designs, which is called

**Shared elements between Activities.**

The idea behind this is having two different views in two different layouts and link them somehow with an animation.

Transition framework will then do whatever animations it consider necessary to show the user a transition from one view to another.

Keep this always in mind: the view is not really moving from one layout to another. They are two independent views.

[image]

**Animation between the views will look like**

[image]

### Check [this](https://github.com/lgvalle/Material-Animations) url for more detail of Material design

Comment: err this isn't it at all, try this: https://android.jlelse.eu/a-little-thing-that-matter-how-to-reveal-an-activity-with-circular-revelation-d94f9bfcae28